# Allow caching with Spring MVC mvc:resources tag

Tags: caching, spring-mvc, http-headers

I've configured the Spring 3 MVC Dispatcher servlet at the root of my webapp, and using mvc:resources for serving static content as described in the docs:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources

Google's Chrome browser Audit tells me that the resources are explicitly non-cacheable.  Here are the headers the same browser says is sent with the response:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=31556926, must-revalidate
Content-Length:1022
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Tue, 11 Jan 2011 00:20:07 GMT
Expires:Wed, 11 Jan 2012 06:08:53 GMT
Last-Modified:Mon, 29 Nov 2010 19:53:48 GMT
```

So, what do I need in order to make the resource cacheable?

Comment: did you set the cache-period attribute on the mvc:resources entry in your application config file?

Comment: yep, and you can see the value set in the max-age of Cache-Control.  Tonight I'm going to setup Spring's ETag filter and see if that resolves this problem.

Comment: did the ETag filter fix the problem? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I never configured the ETag filter because I was moved to other priorities, but it seems like after a few days chrome wasn't yelling at me about this anymore.  I'll see if I can check tomorrow and see if it's happy now or still in the same state.

Comment: Just to be sure, what makes you say the resource is "uncacheable" ? As I understand it, it is set to be cached for a year (max-age), only the client must check with the server that the resource has not changed (must-revalidate). Or I am missing something ?

Comment: I was just reporting what Chrome was telling me in the audit, I don't know why it would have interpreted it as "explicitly non-cacheable"

Comment: The uncachable part the request is `must-revalidate`, as it forces a round trip to the server to check the resource has not been updated. I'm banging my head against this one too. On the surface, these seem like really lame defaults to have for static asset hosting.

Answer (score 3):

As of Spring Framework 4.2, [this is now fixed with more flexible `Cache-Control` header values](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-caching).

The `"must-revalidate"` value is now disabled by default, and you can even write something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/static/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(30, TimeUnit.DAYS).cachePublic());
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do the same in version prior to 4.2?

Comment: Not that I know of - at this point in time, upgrading to 4.3 is the best choice anyway as Spring 3.x is EOL in a few days and 4.3 is the new LTS version.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor can help you? Just add it to the list of interceptors:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="cacheMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/ajax/promoCodes">300</prop>
                <prop key="/ajax/options">0</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: javadoc for that class doesn't make it look like it would be what I'm looking for.